# What are the synonum of "This is accepted" for academia writing

Tags: word-choice, academia

I'm looking for an academic synonym for "`This is accepted with`". For example, I want to say `This is accepted with the measure X` or `This is accepted when the X measure increases` or `this is accepted with the classes that always achieve full coverage`. I used it so many times and I would like to use an alternative word to avoid redundancy.

Comment: Accepted by who? For what purpose? By what criteria?

Comment: 'This is accepted with' sounds non-standard in the sense I think you intend it. It means 'Top workers in the field take this to be proven as true when ... [condition X applies]'. Is that really what you mean?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, this is what I mean.

Comment: 'Considered true when' or 'Known to be true when', but in scientific writing even more than on ESL, supporting references are almost always of extreme importance. Weasel statements ('Many believe that ...') are unscholarly.

Answer (score -1):

Some possibilities from [thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/accepted):

- support, endorse, allow, allow for, sanction, recognize, authorize, permit

  > ’Current research *supports/ endorses/ allows for/ sanctions/ recognizes/ authorizes/ permits* the Y result under X conditions.”
- substantiate, corroborate, authenticate, approve, acknowledge

  > 'Top workers in the field *have substantiated/ corroborated/ authenticated/ approved/ acknowledged* So-and-So’s conclusion regarding result Y when condition X applies, through repeatedly reproduced study results'
- confirm, uphold, verify, validate

  > 'Dr. So-and-So, the current leader in this field, *has confirmed/ upheld / verified/ validated* Y when condition X applies'.
- prevalent, prevailing

  > 'In 8 of the last 10 published studies, Y is the *prevailing result* when condition X is applied.
- conventional

  > 'Thought leaders now consider Y a *conventional* result when condition X is applied’.
- in use, in the mainstream

  > 'The Y conclusion when condition X applies is now *in mainstream use* among field researchers in 20 countries.’
- standard operating procedure, customary, usual, well-known, established

  > 'Dr. So-and-So, who is considered by The Academy to be the emerging leader in the field of Fill-In-The-Blank, considers Y to be a *standard operating procedure/ a customary practice/ usual practice/ a well-known result/ established practice* when condition X applies'.